# Как в DllImport указать путь к dll файлу?

Tags: c#

Если я указываю лишь имя

```
[DllImport("example.dll", EntryPoint = "_foo@4")]
private static extern int foo();
```

то поиск dll осуществляется только в папке system32. Хотелось бы подключать dll'ку, находящуюся в одной папке с программой. Как это сделать?

**Добавлено.**

Если, не предпринимая дополнительных действий, просто положить dll в папку с программой и не класть его в system32, ловится исключение:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Не удается загрузить DLL "example.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм поиска DLL может различаться на разных платформах и при разных установках. Подробнее здесь: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx). Но практически наверняка, папка в которой лежит исполняемый файл, входит в просматриваемый путь. Поэтому стоит удостовериться, что вы действительно кладете DLL туда же, где находится exe.